# Map out Windows 8.1 Clicks

Tags: windows, touchpad

I'm new to Windows 8.1 and Windows in general (I prefer Linux). How can you map out the clicks on your trackpad.Specifically, I want this mapping:

```
Right or Left click = Right Click

Control + Right or Left Click = right click
```

Or I wouldn't mind just switching out the right and left clicks. I find it difficult to use the left click on my trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see these docs until now. Here are the docs. The place is change mouse settings:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-mouse-settings#1TC=windows-7